# Laravel homepage doesn't show unless I add /public/ to url

Tags: laravel, iis-10

First of all, I am quite new to Laravel and I want to start a course, but I want to start in my work environment.

We have a server that runs IIS version 10. On there we have a domain running and every "site" is placed under the same URL. We change sites for example: example.com/website1 and example.com/website2.

My Laravel website is running under example.com/Website3 and I cannot enter my laravel website unless I enter example.com/Website3/public/. Otherwise I just get the "Browse through files" page from the website. As shown in the picture below.

I have tried adding a web.config file, but this did not change a thing.
Hopefully someone is able to point me in the right direction, so I can actually start learning Laravel.

[image: BrowseThroughFiles]

Comment: The "DocumentRoot" of your webserver should point to the `public` folder (don't know the equivalent in IIS). You could also use `php artisan serve` from your project folder. (Ideally you'd use a Vhost for each Laravel project)

Comment: You get the "Browse through files" page from the website because you didn't set a [default document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/configure-default-document-iis) in iis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to the tip from brombeer as a reaction to my post.

1. I had to right click my Default Web Site in the IIS manager
2. I had to click Add Virtual Directory...
3. I had to fill in the folder (Example3) which I wanted to point to the DocumentRoot /public/
4. As Physical Path I filled the path to my public folder.
5. When I enter example.com/website3 I now end on the index.php from the public folder.

Comment: I have the same issue but this didn't fix it correctly. I able to access `index.php` from the public folder but I get 404 errors for sub folders! ex. `GET
https://example.com/favicons/favicon-16x16.png   [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]` the correct path must be `https://example.com/cms/favicons/favicon-16x16.png`